# How to model a process which can have 3 different Initialize events

Tags: bpmn

I have a process which can be started from 3 different events, and I'm not really sure what is the right way to model it. This is an approach:

[image]

What is the right way to model it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can have several start events in a BPMN process diagram. Just make sure the consequence is what you want: for every start event that 'fires' you get a separate process instance, independent from all others.

As a side note, I would just recommenend that you work a bit more on the overall consistency of your diagram.

1. Consider to use lanes as a relatively lightweight means of visualising process participants
2. Consider to type your start events: what exactly 'triggers', which 'activity' follows
3. Consider on 'how many' of underlying 'data objects' people work on for each 'trigger'

Just to illustrate a possibility (process modeling at that level is everything else than an 'exact' science)...

[image]

Comment: Recommendations very appreciated